# I broke software updater by making python3 default

Tags: python, symbolic-link

I tried to make Python 3 the default Python version by running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```

This broke Python 2 programs, so I tried reversing the process and finally I tried:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7 10
```

which made `python2.7` the default Python version but Software Updater doesn't run and running `aptdcon` in a terminal gives:

```
bash: /usr/bin/aptdcon: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried reinstalling Python 3 but got:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I revert this mess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue myself. The problem was the broken symlink in `/usr/bin`

First I identified where python3 is. I guessed that the python3 binary would be in a similar folder as python2. So I typed `ls -l /usr/bin/python`.

This gave me `/usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python2.7`.

Since in `/etc/alternatives/` there was no python3, I repeated the process

`ls -l /etc/alternatives/python2.7` gave

`/etc/alternatives/python2.7 -> /usr/bin/python2.7`

A simple `ls /usr/bin/python3.[1-9]` listed all the python binaries available. The one I was interested in was `python3.4`.

Then I simply created a symlink with `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3`.

Problem solved.

Comment: You are diverging from the [Ubuntu standard](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3) where they say they will not do this: `/usr/bin/python will point to Python 3. No, this is not going to happen`.  One view is to think python2 and python3 are different languages with different syntax, not variations of the same language, so Ubuntu's decision to not imply that either in /etc/alternatives or /usr/bin/python seems to take this strong view.

Comment: @maxpolk This answer does not link python to python3, this links python3 to python3.4.